# Is there any tool to view/edit/delete document of Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there any tool to `view/edit/delete` document of Marklogic, like Mongo Management Studio for MongoDb?

Answer (score 4):

Built into MarkLogic is support for WebDav.  You can create a WebDav App Server in the admin console and then any WebDav client can access documents.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/webdav
There are limits to what the webdav protocol supports but this does give basic integration at the document level.

The MarkLogic extension to xmlsh includes a Java GUI providing a basic tree browser for ML, including open, copy, paste, new folder, import, drag&drop.

It is very basic and doesnt work for all types and sizes of documents or handle all the complexities of permissions, collections, property fragments etc.
http://www.xmlsh.org/ModuleMarkLogic

The command is undocumented, but comes with the MarkLogic extension and uses the same configuration variables as put, get, invoke etc.

```
$ xmlsh
$ import module ml=marklogic
$ MLCONNECT=xcc://user@host:8000
$ ml:mlui
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main way would be to use the Query Console very much like you would use a console in an RDBMS to manage content. But instead of SQL, you are using xQuery.

Overview: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/qconsole/walkthru

Comment: I know about query console and we have to write query for every operation we have to do. I am looking for tool through which i can browse the documents and edit it if needed and save it back again like Mongo Management Studio provides for MongoDb.

Answer (score 1):

As DALDEI mentioned webdav is a solution for this. I have been successful with third party webdav file system browsers. Panic Transmit on macos and BitKinex on win are two that have worked well for me.

The MarkLogic model is document based but directories as such are only one way to think about how to organize your data. After many years of app development on MarkLogic I tend to lean most heavily on collections when thinking about how to constrain queries across sets of documents.

One thing that may not be obvious when using webdav app servers is that you will need to set automatic directory creation to true on your target database.

Answer (score 0):

Marklogic comes with the QueryConsole, usually accessible at http://yourHost:port/qconsole/

To view a document you can use `fn:doc("uri of the document")`

Have a look at the functions described here: https://docs.marklogic.com

Comment: Thanks Daniele for your reply. I am looking for something apart from query console to browse the documents.

Answer (score 0):

QConsole as mentioned by the other comes out of the box with MarkLogic, I'd look at that first. It gives you a lot of freedom to do whatever you want.

However, if you are looking for more of a file-browser kind of tool, you might be interested in the Narthex tool: http://developer.marklogic.com/code/narthex. A little old, but I expect it should still work. Code is on Github, so you can file tickets and fork if you need extra features.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks grtjn, will try to use it and will see how it works.

Comment: Able to configure the narthex and see the document at -http://localhost:port/documents. Onclick of the document uri, i am getting 500 internal server error - XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $variants as element(http:variant)* -- Invalid coercion: <http:variant xmlns:http="xdmp:http"><http:media-type><http:type>application</http:type><http:sub-typ...</http:variant> as element(http:variant)
in /document.xqy, at 36:86, in xdmp:invoke("document.xqy", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>750004617763302506</database></options>) in invoker.xqy, at 16:1$_= ()
$db = xs:unsignedLong("750004617763302506")

Comment: I am using Marklogic 8

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic and [**oXygen**](https://www.oxygenxml.com) support WebDAV.

If you are editing XML documents, [oXygen Author](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author/WYSIWYG_Editors.html) provides a "word-like" WYSIWYG editor for a variety of XML vocabularies.

> oXygen offers CSS-based, out-of-the-box visual editing support for a
>   number of important XML documentation frameworks (DITA, DocBook, TEI,
>   XHTML). Also, if you are planning to use other types of XML documents,
>   an API is available for customizing oXygen.

[image]
[image]