# search marklogic gui tool for exploring data base

Tags: marklogic, nosql

I 'm looking for a GUI tool to explore a marklogic data base. I mean a tool like mongochef for mongodb or mysqlworkbench for mysql etc..

I find nothing equivalent for marklogic base.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options for exploring a MarkLogic database.  Probably the most popular is [Query Console](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/qconsole).  It will allow you to [explore](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/qconsole/walkthru#id_52681) the files as a list or run queries in JavaScript, XQuery, SQL, SPARQL Query, or SPARQL Update.  You can also create a WebDAV server pointed to your database and use [a WebDAV Client](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/webdav#id_52283) to walk through documents in your directory tree.  If you'd like a search interface that doesn't require any specialized query language knowledge, you could setup a [Slush generator application for Spring Boot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-marklogic-spring-boot) or [Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slush-marklogic-node).

With all that said, don't expect anything just like mongochef or mysqlworkbench.  Just as those two tools are very different, so too you should expect the tools in the MarkLogic ecosystem to be unique.

Comment: what is the difference between MarkLogic REST API and CORONA ?  they are both rest api in my sense, so why use corona while we can simply use the original rest api ?

Comment: Corona was written before the REST API existed. It's been replaced by the company-supported REST API.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application called QConsole that is installed with MarkLogic. It's available at http://localhost:8000/qconsole. If you click the Explore button at the top, you can view the content of the database and page through its contents.

For a more sophisticated web-based browsing tool, take a look at EXPath Console, which contains a document browser and several other useful database utilities.

https://github.com/fgeorges/expath-ml-console

Another option is to create a WebDAV App Server in MarkLogic and use an external WebDAV browser to view the content. Windows and OSX both have built-in (albeit limited) WebDAV capabilities. Oxygen XML Editor has a good one, and there are standalone WebDAV browser applications available for most OSes.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/webdav

Answer (score 1):

The MarkLogic extension to xmlsh has a simple GUI tree browser for marklogic.
The advantage over QConsole is for large hierarchial data sets.
QConsole (a very good app) uses linear pagination to browse.  If you more then a few hundred documents it can be tedious to find them.
mlui uses a 'standard tree' widget which works well for 'directory like' document structures.

[Is there any tool to view/edit/delete document of Marklogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048704/is-there-any-tool-to-view-edit-delete-document-of-marklogic)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little dated, but still worth mentioning I think, Narthex:

https://github.com/jmakeig/narthex

HTH!